# AS3 Play contents of a symbol

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip

I've grouped a multiple layer 1 frame actionscript driven animation into a symbol. (simply put, imagine a 1 frame image being tweened by code over a few sec, in this symbol)

Now I'd like to play the contents of this symbol using an event listener.

But

stuff_mc.gotoAndPlay(1); and Test Movie doesn't play a thing (doesn't even show the contents of the symbol (the picture) which can actually be seen on stage).

If I go inside the stuff_mc and Test Scene, it works perfectly..

So how do I play stuff_mc from the stage?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you're going to have to post some code. This is a very vague question that, without actual source, will just result in a bunch of speculation.  To add my bit of such, if you have an image that sits on the stage in your MC and you don't see in on the main stage, it must either be off screen or not there at all.  Have your MC trace something each time it loops like its x and y position to make sure it is where you think it is.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, well, I've posted the whole code here as "Thundordan" http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?p=940477&posted=1#post940477 The image in the symbol disappears if I add the glow filter part on stage. (the image disappearing is actually a good sign considering it's supposed to be masked). The problem is the animation doesn't play without the glow filter code nor with it. (unless I test the movie from within the symbol). Read the posts when you have time (notice that I've been asking about a different but somewhat related problem there)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you are using multiple scenes. If that's the case then this is most likely where your problem is. Scenes are generally a bad idea in Flash – Adobe itself admits this.

Comment: No, I'm not, I meant that If I "Test Movie" it doesn't work at all, but if I get inside the symbol and choose "Test Scene" (which plays only the contents of the symbol) it works. I don't actually have scenes.

The stage has like a blank symbol inside of which I put a 1 frame thing which is animated by AS3 code. But the stage wouldn't recognise the fact that there's an animation in there.

Comment: In that case, try what greg posted in the comment above and post your results...that will give a clue as to what is going on. Even though you've put something on the stage, is it the main stage? Did you accidentally put a weird effect on it? Are you exporting to the wrong player? ...There are too many unresolved variables until we look at some code or an FLA.

Comment: If all else fails, why not copy the symbol to a brand new .fla file and publish and see if it works.

Comment: I did. I posted a link in my reply to greg. It has all of my code.

I didn't have time to try to copy the symbol to a new .fla, will try it when I can.

The symbol is on the main stage (with the glow filter AS code on a layer above it). And inside the symbol there's a picture symbol, with the animation (masking) code in a layer above it. 

The glow filter would be the weird effect, and that's what causes the flv generated by "Test Scene" (although it works in the program), when opened as standalone, to freeze (explained more in that thread). But the glow doesn't effect the "Test Movie" problem